# Dropping text at mouse position in textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, drag-and-drop, cursor-position

Despite many similar questions I haven't been able to find the answer. What I would like to do is this:

I have a text box with some text and a couple of pictureboxes with a picture each. If I perform a drag-and-drop from a picture to the textbox, some text should be inserted into the textbox at the position where my cursor is when I make the drop (i.e. at the point where the mouseup event occurs).

The first part is fine:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    // Create custom text ...
    pictureBox1.DoDragDrop("Some custom text", DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

My problem is how to define where to drop the text:

```
private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        textBox1.Text.Insert(CORRECT_POSITION, e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString());
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: I have tried to get the right position with GetCharIndexFromPosition(), but it doesn't seem to return the correct position. The following code does indeed return a character position, but I have no idea where it gets it from. It's clear that it doesn't represent the position of the cursor, though.

```
private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)sender;
    System.Drawing.Point position = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
    int index = textBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(position);
    MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @linurb for right to the point question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the current mouse position to client coords within the TextBox.  Also, you can move the insertion point in the DragOver() event so the user can see where the text will be inserted:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pictureBox1.DoDragDrop("duck", DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    void textBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = textBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(textBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
        textBox1.SelectionStart = index;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
    }

    void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string txt = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        int index = textBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(textBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
        textBox1.SelectionStart = index;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        textBox1.SelectedText = txt;
    }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I got the bonus part to work as well, although I don't understand the duck part. :) It seems to be working just as fine without the MouseMove event (?).

Comment: The MouseMove() event is just a different way to initiate the drag/drop.

Comment: Nice, but... you should really use `DataFormats.UnicodeText`.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to drop on the final index of the textbox... any idea why?